# Very Basic C function

Tags: c

i just created a simple calculator using C.
Now by my code, i am only able calculate operations 1 at a time.
thus what code or loop should i use to redo my calculation or do another one without having ti build and run my program again. 
well here is my code:

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

   float first_value;
   float second_value;
   char Operation;


   printf("Welcome to Shoeb's first calculator :)\nChoose your operation (a for Addition/s for Subtraction/m for Multiplication/d for Division) \nPress  small o when done calculation ^_^\n");

   scanf("%s", &Operation);


    if (Operation == 'a') {

        printf("Type in your first number below.\n");
        scanf("%f", &first_value);

        printf("Type in you second value below.\n");
        scanf("%f", &second_value);

        printf("The result is %f", first_value+second_value);

    }



    if (Operation == 's') {

        printf("Type in your first number below.\n");
        scanf("%f", &first_value);

        printf("Type in you second value below.\n");
        scanf("%f", &second_value);

        printf("The result is %f", first_value-second_value);

   }

    if (Operation == 'm') {

        printf("Type in your first number below.\n");
        scanf("%f", &first_value);

        printf("Type in you second value below.\n");
        scanf("%f", &second_value);

        printf("The result is %f", first_value*second_value);

   }

    if (Operation == 'd') {

        printf("Type in your first number below.\n");
        scanf("%f", &first_value);

        printf("Type in you second value below.\n");
        scanf("%f", &second_value);

        printf("The result is %f\n", first_value/second_value);

   }
       return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: `scanf("%s", &Operation);` --> `scanf(" %c", &Operation);` and use `do..while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename 'int main(void)' to 'int calculator(void)'.  Make a new main:

```
int main(void){
  while(1) calculator();
};
```

Comment: Oh - and fix the UB cockup posted by Sourav :(